# Can we migrate our DB to elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

We have a huge PostgreSQL DB but its very slow in terms of processing, we already have a very good indexing in place with PostgreSQL but it takes a while to get our data from Postgres, we are planning to migrate our DB to Elastic Search, just for Select queries. Can we migrate full functional DB to Elastic Search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah why not, in fact, most of the search applications (like e-commerce) search are powered by search DB(Elasticsearch or Solr) but they are backed by RDBMS(this is the source of truth), Also Elasticsearch index building from these Databases are very common.

RDBMS are good for relational transactional systems but if you want to speed the search queries(instead of creating huge indices in RDBMS) it always makes sense to use Elasticsearch(which also is very performant in case of filters and aggregation).

Comment: Doesn't sound like this answers the question, which is "Can we migrate full functional DB to Elastic Search?" which would include not just updates, but things like stored procedures, triggers, etc.